# How can I end a string randomly and concatenate another string at the end in Python?

Tags: python, string, concatenation

Basicaly I have a user inputted string like:

"hi my name is bob"

what I would like to do is have my program randomly pick a new ending of the string and end it with my specified ending.

For example:

"hi my name DUR."

"hi mDUR."

etc etc

I'm kinda new to python so hopefully there's an easy solution to this hehe

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
import random

s = "hi my name is bob"
r = random.randint(0, len(s))
print s[:r] + "DUR"
```

String concatentation is accomplished with `+`. The `[a:b]` notation is called a slice. `s[:r]` returns the first `r` characters of `s`.

Answer (score 1):

```
s[:random.randrange(len(s))] + "DUR"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want this, but you can do something like the following

```
import random
user_string = 'hi my name is bob'
my_custom_string = 'DUR'
print ''.join([x[:random.randint(0, len(user_string))], my_custom_string])
```

You should read [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html) for the `random` module to find out which method you should be using.

Answer (score 0):

just one of the many ways

```
>>> import random
>>> specified="DUR"
>>> s="hi my name is bob"
>>> s[:s.index(random.choice(s))]+specified
'hi mDUR'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the random module. See an example below:

```
import random
s = "hi my name is bob"
pos = random.randint(0, len(s))
s = s[:pos] + "DUR"
print s
```